# my selenium test C# in chrome. Click property

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium

While working on this project, I have encountered an exception. It is running firefox, but will not run in chrome.

```
        [Test]
public void TheBtcTraderDenemeTest()
{
    _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(_baseUrl);
    Thread.Sleep(1500);
    _driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("btn btn-cust")).Click(); //*** Exception location is this one.
```

An exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.IllegalLocatorException' occurred in WebDriver.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Compound class names are not supported. Consider searching for one class name and filtering the results.

Any ideas on what is going on would be appreciated.

Comment: `"btn btn-cust"` is the problem.  You need to choose one or the other, not both.  Then filter to the correct one (if necessary).  This is exactly what the error message is telling you.

Comment: i think you're wrong

Comment: Thanks for sharing your opinion, @Turgut Kanceltik

Answer (score 2):

Additional information told you everything. You should choose one of the classes, not both of them

Comment: how do i ? Show me an example ?

Answer (score 0):

`By.ClassName` will only accept a **single** CSS class name, by it's very name & definition. You are giving it **two**.

**Two** is 1) `btn` and 2) `btn-cust`.

Therefore it's no longer a "class name" selector but rather a general **CSS Selector**.

So you need to do either of the following:

Use **only** one of them, probably `btn-cust` with `By.ClassName` or keep with what you have but put it into a CSS selector:

```
By.CssSelector("btn btn-cust")
```

FWIW, the exception message tells you exactly what is wrong and is saying the exact same thing as we are here. Please check out your exceptions when they are thrown. They aren't there for fun.